# ANTLR: Unicode Character Scanning

Tags: java, antlr, lexer

Problem: Can't get Unicode character to print correctly.

Here is my grammar:

```
options { k=1; filter=true;
 // Allow any char but \uFFFF (16 bit -1)
charVocabulary='\u0000'..'\uFFFE'; 
}

ANYCHAR :'$'
|    '_' { System.out.println("Found underscore: "+getText()); }
|    'a'..'z' { System.out.println("Found alpha: "+getText()); }
|    '\u0080'..'\ufffe' { System.out.println("Found unicode: "+getText()); }
;
```

Code snippet of main method invoking the lexer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
SimpleLexer simpleLexer = new SimpleLexer(System.in);
while(true) {
try {
Token t = simpleLexer.nextToken();
System.out.println("Token : "+t);

} catch(Exception e) {}

}
}
```

For input **"ठ"**, I'm getting the following output :

```
Found unicode: 
Token : ["à",<5>,line=1,col=7]
Found unicode: 
Token : ["¤",<5>,line=1,col=8]
Found unicode:  
Token : [" ",<5>,line=1,col=9]
```

It appears that the lexer is treating Unicode char "ठ" as three separate character. My aim is to scan and print "ठ".

Comment: Not related to your problem, but I recommend never to "swallow" your exceptions: when things go wrong, you have no idea what happened (and where). Instead of `catch(Exception e) {}` at the very least do: `catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: You are correct sir :) Lesson for me: read the copied code all the way to the end before using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is not in the ANTLR generated lexer, but in the Java stream you pass to it. The stream reads bytes only (doesn't interpret them in an encoding), and what you see is an UTF-8 sequence.

If its ANTLR 3, you can use the [ANTLRInputStream](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/classorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1_a_n_t_l_r_input_stream.html) constructor that takes an ancoding as a parameter:

```
ANTLRInputStream (InputStream input, String encoding) throws IOException
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. 

Also, I realized that I was using antlr.Tool, instead of org.antlr.Tool, and that wasn't generating the Lexer implementation with a constructor that takes ANTLRInputStream.

Comment: I know this is a long shot being over 3 years later. However, do you happen to know how to do something like this for C# and ANTLR4? There is no longer a constructor that uses encoding at all.

Comment: Added answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126507/antlr4-using-non-ascii-characters-in-token-rules/28129510#28129510

Comment: He used `charVocabulary`, which is only available in ANTLR 2. Is there a solution that works with that ANTLR version?