# Does ANTLR for Java support MBCS?

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, antlr, mbcs

I searched and couldn't find much about it. We need to provide the most general support for encodings and such and want to make sure ANTLR is going to be able to handle anything we throw at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java VM uses 16 bit character encoding, so `MBCS` streams must be converted as they are read into the VM.  That's relatively independent of `ANTLR`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some talk about [ANTLRInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631604/antlr-unicode-character-scanning) on stackoverflow (found by looking at ANTLR + unicode in google). Is that enough support for multi-byte-character-set for you?